# Return joined column with kentico get documents

Tags: kentico

I have the following query to get a set of documents with their page views

```csharp
var activityQuery = ActivityInfoProvider.GetActivities()
                .Columns($"COUNT(*) AS [{ColumnNames.PageViews}]", ColumnNames.ActivityValue)
                .WhereEquals(ColumnNames.ActivityType, ActivityTypes.BlogPostView)
                .GroupBy(ColumnNames.ActivityValue)
                .ToString(true);

var query = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments(PageTypes.BlogPost)
                .Columns(_blogCardColumns)
                .Source(src => src.LeftJoin(new QuerySourceTable($"({activityQuery})", "A"), "V.DocumentGUID", "A.ActivityValue"))
                .OrderByDescending(ColumnNames.BlogPostDate)
                .Published(selectOnlyPublished)
                .NestingLevel(1)
                .Path(path);
```

This query works well, but it returns me a set of treenodes and as far as I can see, it doesn't return me the `PageViews` column.

Is there a way to do a query and the result set include the page views column (or is there a way to get it from the treenode element)?

I have tried the following with the results, but it just returns null:

```
var nodes = query.ToList()
nodes.First().GetValue("PageViews");
```

but this returns null, even though if I get the query sql and run it in sql management studio, it returns 28 for PageViews

Comment: I'd check that the `PageViews` column name is in the variable `_blogCardsColumns`.  Failing that, have you though if using a custom query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok as it turns out `.ToList()` returns a treenode collection.  If I change the last line to

```
var dataset = query.Result;
```

It returns a dataset with all the columns I requested in `_blogCardsColumns` and then I can access my pageviews by using

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    int pageviews = int.Parse(dataRow["PageViews"].ToString())
}
```